# GET запрос и модальное окно через якорь

Tags: joomla, get, href

Имеется сайт на joomla. Перехожу на страницу с GET запросом /forum-answers/?q=1

После чего вызываю модальное окно через якорь (форма аутентификации). После проверки логина и пароля - страницу необходимо перезагрузить. Но после перезагрузки ссылка в строке браузера приобретает вид forum-answers/#openLogin

То есть теряется GET параметр. Не могу понять почему и как исправить. Про history api знаю, но хотелось бы без него.

Comment: если кому интересно, сделал так http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539697/217460